# Crear forma redondeada con css

Tags: html, css

Hola espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias de antemano.
Quiero hacer esta forma [image: forma css] para aplicarlo como fondo de una sección en un sitio web que estoy trabajando, probe hacerlo con border radius y clip-path y no pude. como ultima opción pensé en un svg pero si se puede solamente con css me seria de mucha ayuda. muchas gracias.

Comment: lo mejor sería crear un *wave*

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la propiedad de css [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) en elementos html aunque [no todos los navegadores lo admiten](https://www.caniuse.com/css-clip-path), así que lo mejor es usar un `svg`.

## Ejemplos

### Con `svg`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
  <path fill="#0099ff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,288L48,272C96,256,192,224,288,197.3C384,171,480,149,576,165.3C672,181,768,235,864,250.7C960,267,1056,245,1152,250.7C1248,256,1344,288,1392,304L1440,320L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z">  </path>
</svg>
```

### Con `clip-path` sobre elementos html

```css
.wave {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20rem;
 
 background-color: rebeccapurple;
 
 clip-path: path('M0,96L40,117.3C80,139,160,181,240,208C320,235,400,245,480,229.3C560,213,640,171,720,138.7C800,107,880,85,960,69.3C1040,53,1120,43,1200,64C1280,85,1360,139,1400,165.3L1440,192L1440,320L1400,320C1360,320,1280,320,1200,320C1120,320,1040,320,960,320C880,320,800,320,720,320C640,320,560,320,480,320C400,320,320,320,240,320C160,320,80,320,40,320L0,320Z');
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```

## ¿Donde puedo obtener más ondas?

En [getwaves](https://getwaves.io/) hay una forma de hacerlo aleatorio:

1. Creas la onda como más te guste.
2. Seleccionas el símbolo para descargar.
3. Te muestra un `svg`, así que solo copia el valor de `d`:

   ```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path fill="#0099ff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,96L4,...,320Z"></path>
   </svg>
   ```
4. En tu css pegas el valor de `d`:

   ```
    .wave {
        clip-path: path('M0,96L4,...,320Z');
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad border-radius debería funcionar, quizás no te está funcionando porque no le has hecho borde al elemento prueba algo como esto:

```
div{
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Esto hará que un div sea completamente redondo, o sea, un círculo.

Comment: Si, perdón es que estoy escribiendo desde el teléfono y es complejo por el corrector